# Regular Expression to Quickly Update Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio

We have some code that we are trying to replace to deal with localization issues.  Essentially I need to replace code that looks like this:

```
var x = Convert.ToDouble("5");
```

with this:

```
var x = Convert.ToDouble("5",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I thought there might be a RegEx expression that could help me with a find-and-replace search in Visual Studio.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you specify more precisely what the regular expression must match? You've only given one example of parsing a literal string containing a single digit. Could there also be more complicated expressions there, including variables, concatenation, etc?

Comment: @Mark - you are correct.  Anything could be used for the parameter including variables and concatenation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is difficult (impossible?) to write a regular expression that can correctly parse C# code. You could try this but it won't work in every case, such as when the expression contains nested parentheses:

- Find what: `{Convert.ToDouble\([^,]+}\)`
- Replace with: `\1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

A slightly different approach is to get the compiler to parse the code for you, by temporarily adding this class to your project:

```
namespace System
{
    static class Convert
    {
        [Obsolete]
        public static double ToDouble(object o)
        {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static double ToDouble(object o, CultureInfo ci)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can fix the warnings about using obsolete methods and finally remove the temporary class.

Comment: +1 Good approach to driving out unwanted code without the "break it all and then fix it" approach!

Comment: I like this approach as well, and hadn't thought of trying something like this.  I'll keep the thread open to see if anyone else has had similar experiences.

Comment: I like this approach, but won't adding another definition of `System.Convert` cause a compiler error?

Comment: @Justin E. Morgan: Actually it just gives a warning: `The type 'System.Convert' in 'Program.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'System.Convert' in 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.x.xxxxx\mscorlib.dll'. Using the type defined in Program.cs`. That's a good thing because it will remind you to remove the class when you're done using it. It could of course give a compile error if you also use other methods that aren't defined in the class. Incidentally, it's not actually important that the code compiles - it's the warning list that we're interested in.

Comment: Cool, I've learned something useful! This will come in handy if I can resist the temptation to do stupid stuff like writing my own `System.String`. +1